# JAR indexing and getResources

Tags: java, indexing, jar, resources, classloader

It appears to me that [JAR file indexing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#JAR_Index) breaks the mechanics of [`ClassLoader.getResources()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResources-java.lang.String-). Consider the following program:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TryIt {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL[] urls = {
            (new File("a.jar")).getAbsoluteFile().toURI().toURL(),
            (new File("b.jar")).getAbsoluteFile().toURI().toURL()
        };
        URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);
        String[] res = { "foo", "foo/", "foo/arb", "foo/bar", "foo/cab" };
        for (String r: res) {
            System.out.println("'" + r + "':");
            for (URL u: Collections.list(cl.getResources(r)))
                System.out.println(" " + u);
        }
    }
}
```

Now prepare the JAR files mentioned in that program:

```sh
mkdir a/foo b/foo
touch a/foo/arb a/foo/bar b/foo/bar b/foo/cab
echo "Class-Path: b.jar" > mf
jar cfm a.jar mf -C a foo
jar cf b.jar -C b foo
```

If you run `java TryIt`, you will get output like this:

```
'foo':
 jar:file:…/a.jar!/foo
 jar:file:…/b.jar!/foo
'foo/':
 jar:file:…/a.jar!/foo/
 jar:file:…/b.jar!/foo/
'foo/arb':
 jar:file:…/a.jar!/foo/arb
'foo/bar':
 jar:file:…/a.jar!/foo/bar
 jar:file:…/b.jar!/foo/bar
'foo/cab':
 jar:file:…/b.jar!/foo/cab
```

But if you run `jar -i a.jar` to create an index, then the same command as above prints this:

```
'foo':
 jar:file:…/a.jar!/foo
'foo/':
 jar:file:…/a.jar!/foo/
'foo/arb':
 jar:file:…/a.jar!/foo/arb
'foo/bar':
 jar:file:…/a.jar!/foo/bar
'foo/cab':
 jar:file:…/b.jar!/foo/cab
```

The index itself looks like this:

```
JarIndex-Version: 1.0

a.jar
foo

b.jar
foo
```

Doesn't the contract of [`getResources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResources-java.lang.String-) imply that *all* available resources matching the given name should be returned?

> Finds all the resources with the given name.

Doesn't [the JAR File Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#JAR_Index) allow indexed packages to span multiple JAR files?

> Normally one package name is mapped to one jar file, but if a particular package spans more than one jar file, then the mapped value of this package will be a list of jar files.

Is there some specification somewhere which says that what I'm observing is indeed correct (or at least permissible) behavior?

Is there some workaround to get all named resources despite the index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This appears to be a bug.**
I've reported it to Oracle, and it's now in their bug database as [bug 8150615](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8150615).

---

I did some digging around in the OpenJDK sources and found the reson for this behavior in there.

The relevant class here is [`sun.misc.URLClassPath`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/e2117e30fb39/src/share/classes/sun/misc/URLClassPath.java). It contains a (lazily constructed) [list of loaders](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/e2117e30fb39/src/share/classes/sun/misc/URLClassPath.java#l89), and [queries each loader in turn](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/e2117e30fb39/src/share/classes/sun/misc/URLClassPath.java#l239) to assemble its result. However, if a JAR file [contains an index](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/e2117e30fb39/src/share/classes/sun/misc/URLClassPath.java#l840), then the JAR files therein will [explicitely be *excluded*](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/e2117e30fb39/src/share/classes/sun/misc/URLClassPath.java#l842) [from getting added](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/e2117e30fb39/src/share/classes/sun/misc/URLClassPath.java#l486) to the list of loaders. Instead, the loader for the JAR containing the index will [query said index](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/e2117e30fb39/src/share/classes/sun/misc/URLClassPath.java#l1034) for the name in question, and [traversed the resulting list](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/e2117e30fb39/src/share/classes/sun/misc/URLClassPath.java#l1041). But here is the catch: this happens in a method [`URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/e2117e30fb39/src/share/classes/sun/misc/URLClassPath.java#l1023) which returns *a single* `Resource` object. It is not possible for this method to return multiple resources. And as all objects in the index are handled by a single loader, a single resource is all we get.